# library Function and map file in embedded software build

Tags: linker, embedded, executable

We are building an embedded application (ARM Cortex M4) with some third party library (**.a files). Would symbols from that library shows up in map file?

As I understand it map file list all symbols including variable and function names but in my map file, I do not find certain symbol from a linked library listed.

Comment: The map file will include everything that was linked in not everything that was in the library.

Answer (score 0):

A library is a collection of object files in a single file package.  The linker extracts and links only those object files necessary to resolve references from other object files, anything else will be omitted.

So your map file will only show the symbols actually included by the linker, not the entire library.

Your compiler may support a "used" directive for force other wise usreferenced code to be included in the link.